# AndroidNetworking response always returning "connectionError" when using ANRequest and ANResponse

Tags: android, okhttp, android-networking

I'm having a problem with getting the response when using `AndroidNetworking` POST via `ANRequest` and `ANResponse`. The response is always `connectionError`. I have a similar request but my body is an `JSONObject` and it's working successfully. but in this case, I'm using `JSONArray`. I also tried to read this [document](https://amitshekhar.me/Fast-Android-Networking/synchronous_request.html) but still, `connectionError` occurs. Please see the code below

```
 private synchronized String sendTickets(Context context, JSONArray jsonArray) {
    String result = null;

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    AndroidNetworking.initialize(context, okHttpClient);

    ANRequest request = AndroidNetworking.post(MYURL)
            .addHeaders("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeaders("Prefer", "return=representation")
            .addJSONArrayBody(jsonArray)
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build();

    ANResponse response = request.executeForJSONObject();

    if (response.isSuccess()) {
        result = String.valueOf(response.getResult());
        Log.d(ModuleTags.MAIN(), result);
    } else {
        ANError error = response.getError();
        errorHandler(error);
        result = error.getErrorDetail();
    }
    return result;
}
```

and calling on my main app via

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               if(WifiStatus.isWifiEnabled(getContext())){
                   String liveResults = sendTickets(getContext(), jsonArray);
                   Log.i("data",liveResults);
               }
           }
       }).start();
```

Comment: did you validate your internet connection and if your server is working or not and Internet permission I hope you are not making this network call on main thread as this is a synchronous call though it doesn't have anything to do with connection Error

Comment: yes. The wifi is always on

Comment: and what about your server which you are trying to hit just validate it with postman or other api testing tool once if even those are working just check the error code

Comment: Hi, I have tried using this type of `AndroidNetworking` like this https://pastebin.com/k5Ne8xXg and it's responding well. but I didn't use it because I need to wait the response before returning it.

Comment: just check the response in error using -> error.getResponse() 
O/P Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=some url} this happens when you try to hit an api which doesn't exits just print getResponse for request call and see what does it say

Comment: the response is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203650/discussion-between-manoj-mohanty-and-rubick).